# Can I do stuff before I take the three steps back after Shemonah Esrei?

Tags: halacha, hefsek-interruption, shemoneh-esrei

If I finish davening Shemonah Esrei and I'm about to take three steps back and do the bowing procedure, can I first do something like pick up my cell phone and put it in my pocket or close a sefer or anything else that doesn't involve  talking or moving  before I take the steps backwards?

Comment: Bowing happens before the steps back.

Comment: As is thus question is not very interesting. Providing a reason to do such a thing would help. For instance: Some nudnik comes late and starts shemona esrei right behind you while you are already up to modim. Now you are basically stuck. Or of course more simply you davened a bit quicker than the guy behind you and can't go back yet.

Answer (score 1):

According to Halachipedia [Taking Three Steps Back](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Taking_Three_Steps_Back) the answer appears to be **No**. The three steps back is part of the shmoneh esrai and should not be interrupted.

> After Shemonei Esrei, one should make take three steps backwards while
>   bowing like a servant parting from his master. **If one didn't do
>   so, it is as if one didn't pray**.[4]
>
> [Gemara Yoma 53b](http://www.sefaria.org/Yoma.53b?lang=he-en), Tur 123:1, Kaf HaChaim 123:1

---

Note that the actual quote from the gemara is

> The Gemara comments that this was also taught in a baraita: One who
>   prays must take three steps backward upon concluding his prayer and
>   then recite: Peace. And if he did not do so, it is better for him not
>   to have prayed, as his actions are disrespectful toward God.

---

Resuming the citation from Halachipedia

> There’s an absolute obligation to take 3 steps back after Shmoneh Esrei
>   and wait there until the Sheliach Tzibbur gets to Kedusha or at
>   least starts Chazarat HaShas. [5]
>
> An individual who finishes Shmoneh Esrei should take take three steps
>   back anf wait there the time it takes for the שליח Tzibbur to reach
>   Kedusha or in extenuating circumstances at least the time it takes to
>   walk 4 amot (3 seconds or so).
>
> If one doesn’t wait after taking the 3 steps back it appears that one
>   didn’t take the 3 steps back really in order to depart from Hashem
>   respectfully. [6]
>
> It’s proper to take three steps forward only after waiting the proper time (subsequent to taking three steps back). [7]

Comment: Do the 3 steps back before öseh shalom bimromov" count for this?

Comment: The gemara doesn't say that it's as if he didn't pray.

Comment: @Ploni The halachipedia entry is what says that it is as if one did not pray. I added the actual quote from the Gemara to show what is said there. I do not have the full quotes from the other sources in footnote 4.